# Multiple StreamBuilder using a static Stream and associated firebase reads cost?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-streambuilder

For a single app instance (i.e. one user running a flutter web app), what would be the number of reads for the below example?

My app has firestore as database where a collection has 10 docs. I have created a static stream like below in a class named `MyWidgetClass`.

```
static Stream<List<MyData>> readJobs() async* {
    var stream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('jobs')
        .where("timeline.start_dt",
            isGreaterThan: DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: numPastDays)))
        .snapshots()
        .map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs.map((doc) => MyData.fromMap(doc)).toList());
    await for (final snapshot in stream) {
      yield snapshot;
    }
  }
```

Then, two other widgets (2 other separate classes), listens to the same stream including `MyWidgetClass` where stream was defined as below:

```
  Stream<List<MyData>>? jobStream;
  late StreamSubscription _jobStreamSubscription;

  stream() {
    _jobStreamSubscription = jobStream!.listen((event) {
      jid = event.map((e) => {e.jid: e.jobDetail.client_uid}).toList();
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    jobStream = MyWidgetClass.readJobs();
    stream();
    super.initState();
  }
```

Does Firebase consider these three different class as separate listeners and read count equals 30, or read count will still be 10?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is showing only a single query, which means there is only one listener here for each time `readJobs` is invoked.  If you invoke readJobs once, you will have one listener with one set of results being billed.  If you decide to share the resulting data with other parts of your code, that doesn't change the behavior or cost of that one query - the Stream isn't going to do anything extra on Firestore to add costs.

Comment: No, I mean the same code is used but different widgets. So, `MyWidgetClass.readJobs()` is called in total 3 times in my app in three different widgets. What I get from your answer is if I somehow pass these results to all widgets then, no extra cost. But would like to know what will happen in my case.

Comment: If it causes 3x reads, what is best method which can be used here. Currently, I am thinking of trying creating a common parent widget of all and read the stream there and then pass into a variable to 3 stateful widgets. Let me know if more info is required. Thanks.

Comment: If you call readJobs three times, then you will be charged for the results of all three queries.

Comment: Listening stream once in a parent widget and passing data to other widgets does not work as Stream Builder needs stream to auto update all widgets. Is there any way around to listen once to stream and auto update all widgets depending on that stream data (given we are on that child widget) ??